# AWK/SED - why my script won't work finding substring between two keywords

Tags: bash, command-line, sed, awk

Consider this ldd output for my executable:

```
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x003a5000)
    libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0 => ./libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0 (0x00710000)
    libBIBusTK.so => ./libBIBusTK.so (0x00b68000)
    libCCLIDOM.so => ./libCCLIDOM.so (0x00a08000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x00357000)
```

Here my interesting part is just this substring in each line:

```
                    ./libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0
                    ./libBIBusTK.so
                    ./libCCLIDOM.so
                    /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1
```

Therefore I am using awk to achieve this, first I tried:

```
ldd ./BIBusTKServerMain | awk -F "=>" '{print $2}'
```

which gives me all the substring after "=>" symbol.

Then I tried one more step:

```
ldd ./BIBusTKServerMain | awk -F "=>" '{print $2}' | awk -F "(0x" '{print $1}'
```

which throws an error:

```
awk: fatal: Unmatched ( or \(: /(0x/
```

Note that if I tried this:

```
ldd ./BIBusTKServerMain | awk -F "=>" '{print $2}' | awk -F "0x" '{print $1}'
```

It produces:

```
./libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0 (
./libBIBusTK.so (
./libCCLIDOM.so (
/usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (
```

What was wrong in my origial awk script?
I have also tried the sed alternative:

```
sed -n '/=>/,/\(0x/p' lddInfo.txt
```

Doesn't work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following sed should work:

```
ldd ./BIBusTKServerMain | sed 's/^.* => \([^ ]*\) .*$/\1/'
```

Or this awk can also work:

```
ldd ./BIBusTKServerMain | awk '$3 ~ /^\.?\// {print $3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you simply try :

```
awk '{print $3}'
```

what is the reason behind not using this?

```
ldd ./BIBusTKServerMain | awk '{print $3}'
```

or you can also use:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/=\> ([^\s]*)\s/)'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works here (GnuSed under windows so the quotes need changing)

```
sed "s/ .* \(.*\) .*/\1/" test.txt
```